# How stretch the picture in CropImageView?

Tags: android

I use library  com.edmodo.cropper.CropImageView
How to set the image to the entire height and width view?

```
<com.edmodo.cropper.CropImageView xmlns:custom="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
                                      android:id="@+id/imageCrop"
                                      android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                                      android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                                      android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                                      android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                                      android:layout_alignParentStart="false"
                                      android:layout_above="@+id/linearLayout5"/>
```

Comment: Did you solve yet ??

Answer (score 1):

Try this Sample Git Project .[Super easy component for Android to crop an image](https://github.com/joshdholtz/CropImageView). I hope it helps you .

Answer (score 0):

you need to set scaleType to fitxy like following

```
android:scaleType="fitXY"
```